# Profiling only user defined functions pstats

Tags: python, profiling, pstats

I'm trying to use Stats() from the pstats module as such:

```
    p = Profile()
    p.runcall(wrangle_file,input_filename="test.csv",output_file="solution.csv",metrics=True)
    stats = Stats(p)
    stats.strip_dirs()
    stats.sort_stats('cumulative')
    stats.print_stats()
```

However, when I do print_stats, I'm getting the calls to library functions as well. Is there a way I can filter these to just print the calls to my functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter modules by passing a module name in the `print_stats()` function.

Assuming the name of your Python file is `my_python.py`, you'd do `print_stats("my_python")`.

You can also pass in function names.